# "Es erhellt auch ..."

Tags: idiom

"Es erhellt auch ..." seems to be an old idiom in German scientific/philosophical language. Just two examples:

**"*Es erhellt auch*, dass B sich nicht mit D austauschen lässt, da es statthaft ist, dass D und A zugleich in einen Gegenstande enthalten sein können."**

**"*Es erhellt auch* von einer anderen Seite, dass, was als wirkliche Realisation einer Idee gelten soll, nicht etwa ein blosses Geschöpf, sondern ein ..."**

How would you translate it - "It appears that ..."?

Comment: _It discloses also ..._

Comment: Is the “es” in the preceding sentence?

Comment: Where are these examples from?

Comment: The proper (and relatively literal) translation to English would be "it is enlightening that..."

Comment: @tofro: Das wäre "Es ist erhellend, dass", "It enlightens" müsste "Es erhellt" sein, oder?

Comment: Sowohl "it is enlightening", als auch "it enlightens" bedeuten "es erhellt".

Comment: Has this possibly confused with *erhalten, es erhält*, in the sense of resulting, or sustaing?

Answer (score 3):

I have never encountered this kind of (intransitive) *erhellen* before. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erhellen) (2b), [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/erhellen) (3) and [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=3,848,36) (1) all have it and agree on the meaning:

> (Daraus) wird klar, daß …
> Es folgt (daraus), daß … / Es ergibt sich (daraus), daß …
>
> (From this) it becomes clear that …
> It follows (from this) that …

Just like more usual *sich ergeben (aus)*, *klar werden (aus)* the verb may be accompanied by the preposition *aus*, indicating the logical antecedent.

> »Unser Volk … ist in seiner großen Mehrheit… von den Prinzipien des Gemeinguts durchdrungen; es ist, wenn man sich so ausdrücken darf, instinktiv, traditionell Kommunist. […] **Daraus erhellt**, daß unser Volk, ungeachtet seiner Unwissenheit, viel näher zum Sozialismus steht als die Völker des westlichen Europas, obwohl diese gebildeter sind.« ([source](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Engels,+Friedrich/Soziales+aus+Ru%C3%9Fland/Soziales+aus+Ru%C3%9Fland?hl=daraus+erhellt))
>
> “Our people … in its great majority … is permeated with the principles of common ownership; it is, if one may use the term, instinctively, traditionally communist. […] **It is clear from this** that our people, despite its ignorance, is much nearer to socialism than the peoples of Western Europe, although the latter are more educated.” ([source](https://marxists.catbull.com/archive/marx/works/1874/refugee-literature/ch05.htm))

Note that the meaning of intransitive *erhellen* is sharply different from the transitive one, as indicated by the translations given above. Firstly, intransitive *erhellen* has lost the meaning of *illuminate*. Look at transitive *erhellen*:

> In diesem Essay findet sich **ein erstaunlicher Satz, der schlaglichtartig das Problem erhellt**, das für die meisten Filmkritiker, Filmtheoretiker und Drehbuchlehrer im Dunkeln bleibt.
>
> … an astonishing sentence that abruptly illuminates the problem …

In this example, *ein erstaunlicher Satz* is the agent of illumination in the usual metaphorical sense of intellectual enlightenment. Now compare intransitive *erhellen*:

> Eines muß also das Regierende und Leitende sein, und dies muß den Namen des Alleinherrschers oder Kaisers führen. **Und so erhellt, daß** Monarchie oder Kaisertum zum Heil der Welt notwendig sei. ([source](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/%C3%9Cber_die_Monarchie))
>
> And so it follows that …

The subject is the subordinate clause introduced by *daß*. However, that clause does not denote the agent of illumination, but the logical consequent of an implication. Recall from the earlier example that intransitive *erhellen* can occur with a prepositional object headed by *aus*, denoting the logical antecedent. This is another feature that distinguishes it from the transitive variant.

Comment: Nice references. I too never encountered this but my first association was "beleuchtet", meaning that a previously mentioned fact/result gives some kind of spotlight to the following thoughts. I can't really describe that idiom in English. "Das wirft ein (anderes/ neues) Licht auf ..." or "in dem Licht erscheint ...".

Comment: @hajef *Es leuchtet ein, daß…* seems very close.

Comment: It's another point of view and another idiom but now that you mention it ... it fits even better. Thank you.

Comment: @hajef In hindsight, the metaphor of light is misleading in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

In context of the question and the examples I would translate (or better interpret) it with "it shows/it's showing, that...".

In general I would use "beleuchten" in German instead of "erhellen".

For example if you want to investigate something closer, you can say "etwas genauer beleuchten".

Answer (score 1):

It is quite straight forward:

- German *hell* (adjective) = English *bright, light*
- German *erhellen* (verb) = English *lighten, enlighten*
- German *erhellend* (participle) = English *enlightening*

Participle:

> Es ist erhellend, dass
>   It is enlightening, that

Verb:

> Es erhellt, dass
>   It enlightens, that

Comment: "It enlightens, that" is not English. I don't think there's a good translation.

Comment: A better translation would probably use "to illuminate sth.", like "It also illuminates that B can't be interchanged with D..."

Comment: *It is enlightening that* means the same thing in English.

Answer (score -1):

To start from the beginning: no, this is no dated fixed phrase, the whole word *erhellen* fell out of favour.

The mostly closely translations into English are *enlighten* (sharing that dated touch) or *highlight*.

The assumed equivalence of **knowledge** and **perception** (especially optical perception) is not specific to German, but quite universal. (Note that in eVIDence the Latin stem of *videre*, i. e. too see, persists.) *Put some additional light on* therefore translates to giving some additional knowledge.

This occurs in two qualities, both addressed by *erhellen*:

1. Provide knowledge, where none was before; in English this would
   translate to *uncover*, *reveal* or *enlighten*. An example of this would
   be the sentence: "Der Polizei gelang es bisher nicht, die
   Hintergründe der Tat zu erhellen."
2. Emphasizing knowledge, which may
   have been present, but not considered at all or as not relevant, translating to *highlight*.

For your first example I found another reference [in Brockhaus (1837)](http://www.zeno.org/nid/20000821845): There it seeem to translate to *imply*.

> Aus dem Vorhergehenden erhellt zugleich, daß im Dreieck keine Diagonale möglich ist, weil darin jeder Winkel unmittelbar den beiden andern benachbart ist [...]